# how to resolve error npm ERR! code ENOENT, npm ERR! syscall lstat?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I want to initialize create-react-app typescript template and get under error

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\m.namazi\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\m.namazi\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I recently installed node@20.10.0 and get the above error, before I install the latest version of Node I get the warning npm global config was depricated!

Answer (score -1):

The error message you encountered, "npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\m.namazi\AppData\Roaming\npm'", suggests that npm is unable to find the specified file or directory.

This issue can occur due to various reasons. Here are a few potential solutions to resolve it:

1. Verify npm Installation: Confirm that npm is installed correctly on your system. You can check the npm version by running the following command:

   `npm -v`

If npm is not installed or the version is not displayed, you may need to reinstall Node.js, which includes npm.

2. Clear npm Cache: Clearing the npm cache can help resolve certain issues. Run the following command to clear the npm cache:

   `npm cache clean --force`

Once the cache is cleared, try running your npm command again to see if the issue persists.

3. Reinstall npm: If the above steps don't resolve the problem, you can try reinstalling npm globally

   `npm uninstall -g npm`

After these steps, I am sure you can create react app

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I have had this problem it has been due to version or configuration conflicts, that can be very hard to solve. A simple solution is to start up a brand new project, for example npx create-next-app@latest if it is a Next.js project, ensuring that configurations are entirely up to date. Then remove the boilerplate and copy in your code. Problem fixed.